# Add request timeout in Python cx_oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am using cx_Oracle 6.4.1

Here is how I make connection:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user, db_pwd, dsn=dsn, encoding = "UTF-8", nencoding = "UTF-8")
def get_connection():
    try:
        if connection is not None:
            connection.ping()
            logger.info('Using the existing connection')
            return connection
        else:
            return get_connection()

    except cx_Oracle.InterfaceError as e:
        logger.info('%s: %s' % (e, 'Creating a new connection'))
        return get_connection()

cxn = self.get_connection()
cursor = cxn.cursor()
cursor.prepare(write_sql)
cursor.executemany(None, insertion_list, batcherrors=True)
```

However, I encounter problems that for some reasons my program sometimes waited too long to get query results from the remote DB. I do not have any control on the DB.

So I'd like to set a timeout, either using cx_Oracle or Python code: if the query gets timeout, call get_connection() and resend the query. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to cx_Oracle 7+ and also make sure you have Oracle client libraries 18 or later.  Then you can use [`callTimeout`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/connection.html#Connection.callTimeout).  There's bit of overview in a [Python Office Hours session](https://youtu.be/tnPHKJQaeE8?t=900) webcast recording.

The other option is to configure your sqlnet.ora file with various settings like sqlnet.recv_timeout, see the cx_Oracle doc [Network Configuration](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/ha.html#network-configuration).